# Angular-UI router not working in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using the Ionic Framework and am having trouble attempting to use the Angular-ui router. The first block of code below functions perfectly. However, as soon as I remove `ng-controller="LoginController as login"` and move this into `controller` and `controllerAs` attributes in my route none of the Angular code within my view works anymore. I thought I understood routing, but this issue is tripping me up.

app/login/login.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">
  <ion-content ng-controller="LoginController as login">

    Email: <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
    Password: <input type="text" ng-model="login.password">

    <br><br>

    <button ng-click="login.createUser()">Create User</button>

    <br><br>

    <button ng-click="login.removeUser()">Remove User</button>

    <p ng-if="login.message">Message: <strong>{{ login.message }}</strong></p>
    <p ng-if="login.error">Error: <strong>{{ login.error }}</strong></p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Code that seems to "break" my view, app.config.js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'app/layout/menu.html'
    })

    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'login'
    })
...
```

Comment: could you share with us your error message?

Comment: @eugene, there wasn't an error message actually. The page rendered fine, but all Angular code was "disabled" for lack of a better term. No bindings or functions attached to controllers would work. The tip below solved it, setting controller to `loginController as login`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginController as login'
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Odd issue, as I'd thought setting 'controllerAs' was the proper way.

Comment: it is the proper way, but is currently is not supported in Ionic

Comment: Thanks it fixed it. But could you explain why was the controller being called twice?