# Angular JS controller called twice (ng-controller)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ng-controller

I'm developping an ionic application and when using angular for login my controller is called twice, 
I've looked through all the others similar questions but didn't find a solution .

The problem is even when I remove the `ng-controller="LoginCtrl as lgnCtrl"`
I get my controller called once but without two-way databinding.

here is my route file :

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
  url: "/login",
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: "app/user/loginView.html",
      controller: "LoginCtrl",
      controllerAs: "lgnCtrl"
    }
  }
})

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

here is my controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
.controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

function LoginCtrl($state, $storage, $translate, $ionicPopup, LoginService, messageService) {
    var lgnCtrl = this;
    console.log("user dash 1zz");
    return lgnCtrl;
}
```

and here is my views:
loginView.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="loginView" id="signinBlk">
   <ion-content>
       <div class="list list col span_1_of_2 "  ng-controller="LoginCtrl as lgnCtrl">
   </div>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you already define your controller in route you dont need to define controller in html template remove the ng-controller attribute with value form html template then run it will run just once

Comment: But, the problem is when i do that i have no more the two waydata banding: my `ng-click` is not catched in controller and I cannot get the controller scope

Comment: you have because your route config manag all things you have as name no worried

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand.
I mean, that when I  remove the ng-controller, ng-click is not triggered in controller and don't execute my click function . 
so what to do ?

Comment: ok change the state
.state('login', {
  url: "/login",
  views: {
    'main': {
      templateUrl: "app/user/loginView.html",
    }
  }
})

Comment: dont define the controller in config

Comment: just define only in template try and tell me

Comment: Yes, when I remove the  'controller' and 'controllerAs' from the state, i get only one call . But it it really a good thing ? should I really remove all controller, and controllerAs attributes in states and keep them in templates to have my controller executed once?

Comment: yes but i really cant understand why the ng-click in not working when you remove the ng-controller attribute because if i define the controller in route config i dont need to assign controller in html

Comment: yes, it may be a problem in the state declaration. I'm beginner in angularjs dev

Comment: this is a concept of controller alias when we define the controller with as keyword we have to use this keyword not scope and it will run fast then $scope it is good trick and handle the parent child data managment thanks if want any kind angular help ask me any time no issue

Comment: Yes, I have read that in https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide . Thanks for your help, I should find a way to keep controller in the state and remove `ng-controller` from my template all with keeping data binding logic

Comment: HERE IS MY SOLUTION :     I should define   `controller: "LoginCtrl as lgnCtrl" ` in state and not `controllerAs` as attribute ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269357/angular-ui-router-not-working-in-ionic-app

Comment: great akram  this is best

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having this

ng-controller="LoginCtrl as lgnCtrl"

in html, we can have this in the controller when the route is defined with a controller, for example in the controller, it will go like this

```
$routeProvider
        .when("/", { templateUrl: "views/abc.html", controller: "LoginCtrl as lgnCtrl", caseInsensitiveMatch: true });
```

it worked like a charm

the functions in the controller are only called once.