# Angular js : Controller calls twice

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to integrate angularjs into my existing rails app. Everything is working fine except my screenCast angular controller is called multiple times. I have searched stack overflow for last 5 hrs, but found no solution for this.

screencast.coffee

```
angular.module('AngularCasts').controller 'ScreencastsCtrl',($scope,Screencast, $location, $routeParams) ->
 alert("hello");
 $scope.screencasts=Screencast.query()

 $scope.selectedScreencast = null
```

app.coffee is

```
angular.module('AngularCasts', [
'templates',
'ngRoute',
'ngResource', 
])

.config ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) ->
 $routeProvider
  .when('/screencasts/new',
    templateUrl: "screencasts/form.html"
    controller: "ScreencastsCtrl"
  ).when('/screencasts',
    templateUrl: "screencasts/index.html"
    controller: "ScreencastsCtrl"
  ).when('/screencast/:id/edit',
    templateUrl: "screencasts/update_form.html"
    controller: "EditScreencastsCtrl"
 )
```

and my scrrencast.coffee factory is

```
angular.module('AngularCasts').factory 'Screencast', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/api/screencasts/:id', id: '@id',{
    'create': {method: 'post'}
    'update': { method: 'patch', id: '@id'}
    'destroy':{method:'delete'}
  }  
]
```

When I load the app for the first time, everything is working fine, but when I change the route or go to different pages my controller is called twice.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's probably redirection from ui-router as you use same controller everywhere, try dummy controller for different routes so you know which one is called, also `alert` is bad for debugging as it stops execution, `console.log` is better

Comment: i create new controller for edit but screencasts controller is still called twice.

Comment: Do you use `ng-controller="ScreencastController as ..."` somewhere in your html?

Comment: no, i check this already.

Comment: Can you post your `a tag`? I want to se how you define it

Comment: she's  not using a tag ,she's redirect back after creating or editing a record.

Comment: yup exactly. i'm doing the same.

Comment: Then most likely the redirection is malformed - happens especially when you use `#/`, in short the router process the url and changes it to fit the standard

Comment: my routes are posted above what changes should i need to do .

Comment: do you sue html5mode, how does your redirection looks like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269807/1643143 this is the solution but without explaination

Answer (score 0):

**1:** You are using same controller for two templates that may cause controller call twice

```
 .when('/screencasts/new',
        templateUrl: "screencasts/form.html"
        controller: "ScreencastsCtrl" //same controller
      ).when('/screencasts',
        templateUrl: "screencasts/index.html"
        controller: "ScreencastsCtrl" //same controller
```

**2:** check your template and route you may have declare controller twice

```
 in template: ng-controller="ScreencastController as ..

   in route: controller:'ScreencastController'
```